# How to use simulate the action of clicking button with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use JavaScript to simulate the action of clicking buttons. How do I achieve it? Can I achieve it with jQuery?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with jquery. Use `trigger` function. Here [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Here is sample:

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Is this solution in any way to be preferred over the vanilla `.click()` method? Is there perhaps some runtime cost difference between the two?

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in IE. Anyone else? `$(this).trigger('click');`

Comment: Disregard, can't seem to add click after adding `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 28):

You can execute the click event handler assigned to a button control:

```
$("#mybutton").click();
```

Answer (score 14):

Simply [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$("#theButton").click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try following code e.g.:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".class_name").trigger('click');  
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code will print clicked two times one from `$('.submitBtn').click();` and other `$('.submitBtn').trigger('click')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.submitBtn').on('click', function() {

   console.log("Clicked!");

  })

$('.submitBtn').click();
$('.submitBtn').trigger('click')



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button menu="submitBtn" class="submitBtn len4 btn" title="submit" data-code-m="sbm.submit"> Click me
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in this 'anonymous document ready function' will make sure the button is there before you click it. Just in case it tries to click before the element you want to click is loaded. This would fix that issue.

Also, remember that an ID uses a hash (i.e. #close-button) but if you want to click an element that has a CLASS then swap the hash for a single dot (i.e. .close-button).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#close-button").trigger('click');    
});
```