# Simulate a click on js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem on my website. I have a `<div id="test">` which is `display:none` by default.
Now, when I click on the button it changes to `display:block`, but in my div a popup is displayed which disappears when I make a click.
So I need to simulate a click so that the another div does not show.
I tried :

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('class','display-block');
  document.getElementById('test').click();
</script>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you give some more details about your problem? Could not able to understand it properly? What you want to achieve and what is your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use simulate the action of clicking button with JQuery or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015054/how-to-use-simulate-the-action-of-clicking-button-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: if you want to use a javascript check here: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
// element you click to execute the display   
$('#button').on('click', function(){      
      $('#test').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do it:

```
$('#test').click()
```

or

```
$('#test').trigger("click");
```

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/eq9c2p2c/

**update**

You need to add `click` event, then you just `trigger` it.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="test">click</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("border")
})
$('#test').click()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eq9c2p2c/2/

Comment: The "test" is a div not a button

Comment: So I want to simulate a click over the div

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.trigger()`
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('#test').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('test')` returns a plain DOM node which doesn't do much.  If you use `$('#test')` you will get the same DOM node, but wrapped in jQuery.

jQuery provides a `.click()` function on these "wrapped" nodes, which will simulate a click on the button for you:

```
$('#test').click();
```

(which is just a shortcut for `.trigger('click')` - read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666577/1136527))

is the same as

```
$(document.getElementById('test')).click();
```