# Is it possible to get javascript to click on a button in an iframe after it loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am loading an `iframe`, which logs a user into a site within the `iframe`. Once they are logged in, there is an OK button that pops up which a user must click to continue. This button has the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="close" value="OK">
```

To load the `iframe`, I am using the following:

```
 <form id="login" target="frame" method="post"
 action="http://xxxx.com/app/1607141016/auth/login?&password=xxx&username=xxxxx">
 </form>

 <iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>

 <script type="text/javascript">
// submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
document.getElementById('login').submit();

// once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
iframe.onload = function() {
    if (iframe.src != "http://xxxx.com") {
        iframe.src = "http://xxxx.com";
    }
}
 document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", functionToRun, false);

   </script>
```

Is there a way to get JavaScript to click the button when the content of the `iframe` has loaded?

Comment: If the domain's are different then no, as cross-origin security rules prevent that

Comment: You could simply load the form response into a div. Then it's easy to automatically click the button, but guess you have to fiddle with the loaded code a bit to get the button working again...

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015054/how-to-use-simulate-the-action-of-clicking-button-with-jquery-or-javascript